# CSS bug. A line appeared and I can't make it dissapear

Tags: php, html, css

I am coding up a page and I have placed a form in a container-fluid div. And it made a line to appear and I can't make it dissapear.

This is the page : http://sacim-design.esy.es/contact.php

This is a screenshot with the border : [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXZuO.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is an empty `<legend></legend>` tag inside your form. It has a border-bottom rule. Just remove this element.

Answer (score 5):

Remove html tag `<legend>`or restyle it

**CSS**

```
legend{
border:none;
}
```

> Beware, you are using bootstrap styles..to make your custom styles you
>   need to overwrtite them